# Magento widgets not showing for template

Tags: magento

I have created a new template for storefront and had few widgets that was linked to old template.

I ran a small db script that duplicated all old template widgets to new  template.

Everything worked fine and the widgets are getting duplicated, but the widgets is not displaying for new template till I manually opened the new widget and save it manually from admin.

Does anybody have any idea regarding this? why it is behaving in that order.

Answer (score 0):

Magento has it's own system cache that runs on a clock, and sometimes it seems to never kick in, requiring you to manually add the widget through the Admin. If you're using Magento version 2.1+, which I'm assuming you are, in the Admin portal, click the Settings icon on the menu on the left then select Cache Management near the bottom.

[image]

Now, if your site is in Production and it's live, those should all be enabled (or fine tuned to your specific needs based on your site), but if you're still in the Staging phase and still in development, I'd recommend you disable everything to make life a little bit easier. If you do decide to disable everything, prior to doing so, Flush the Cache Storage as well as the Magento Cache, then select all and from the dropdown in the upper left, select Disable then Submit.